# How can one reconcile statistics with this pasuk in Koheles?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah, kohelet

The [pasuk in Koheles](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%98_%D7%99%D7%90) states:

> שַׁבְתִּי וְרָאֹה תַחַת הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ כִּי לֹא לַקַּלִּים הַמֵּרוֹץ וְלֹא לַגִּבּוֹרִים הַמִּלְחָמָה וְגַם לֹא לַחֲכָמִים לֶחֶם וְגַם לֹא לַנְּבֹנִים עֹשֶׁר וְגַם לֹא לַיֹּדְעִים חֵן כִּי עֵת וָפֶגַע יִקְרֶה אֶת כֻּלָּם.

How does this make sense?

Aren't people who are swift more likely to win races, and people who are mighty more likely to win wars (etc.)?

Please provide sources, preferably from Rishonim, who address this question.

Comment: See Rashi. It's not a statistical statement; it's saying that the speed of the swift and the strength of the mighty won't save them when their time is up.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for pointing this out. I don't think Rashi is in accordance with peshuto shel mikra. I'll cite the Rashbam's answer below as an example of peshuto shel mikra.

Comment: My pre-edit comment was actually your answer before I realized what Rashi was getting at. In any case, I don't see it as a contradiction; rather, one follows from the other. The swift don't always win the race, therefore they can't rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

Rashbam to Koheles says:

> שאינה שוה להם מרוצתם **תדיר** שאע"פ שהם קלים במרוצתם לרוץ עת ופגע ומקרה יקרה להם כמו לשאר בני אדם ולא לגיבורים המלחמה שאין נצחון מלחמות עומד להם **תדיר** כי מקרה אחד להם ואף לא לחכמים לחם **בכל עת** בשביל חכמתם ואף לא לנבונים עושר בכל עת ברוב תבונתם **שפעמים** שהם יורדין לעניות ואף לא ליודעים חן בכל עת **פעמים** שאין להם חן ושנואים הם בעיני הבריות שהרי מקרה אחד יקרה לכולם

Accordingly, the passuk means that the swift don't **always** win the race, etc., but it is not inconsistent with the reality that fast people are more likely to win races.